# Change default line width in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to change the default behaviour of circuitikz by changing the line width.
The components should be less thick and the lines thicker.

I found a similar way to get the same look and feel using the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, textcomp, gensymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5,transform shape] 
\draw (0,0)
to [open, v^>=$V_{in}$, o-o] ++(0,3)
to ++(0.5,0)
to [L, l=$L_{RX}$, -] ++(1,0)
to [C, l=$C_{RX}$, -] ++(1,0)
to ++(0.5,0)
++(0,-3)
to [Do, l=$D_R$, *-*] ++(0, 3)
to ++(1,0)
++(0,-3)
to [C, l_=$C_D$, *-*] ++(0, 3)
to ++(0.5,0)
to [L, l=$L_C$, -] ++(1.5, 0)
to ++(0.5,0)
to [C, l=$C_{DC}$, *-*] ++(0, -3)
++(0,3)
to ++(1.5,0)
to [open, v^<=$V_{DC_{out}}$, o-o] ++(0,-3)
++(0,3)
to ++(2,0)
to [R, l=$R_L$, -] ++(0, -3)
to (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

and getting this result
[image: Rectifier]

compared to the default one
[image]

Is there a way to directly increase the size of the lines (and only the lines)?

**-- EDIT 1 --**

I would like to have an option similar to `\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}` to set also the line width.

Comment: Use the `line width` option: `\begin{circuitikz}[line width=0.1pt,...]`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos It also increases the line in the bipoles.
I would like to have an option similar to \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1} for setting also the line width.

Comment: I think the 1 in `\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}` means the bipoles should have the same width as the lines. Setting e.g. `\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=0.5}` or `\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=2}` makes it half or double width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the comments to the question I was able to find a suitable solution.

Setting the `\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}` should mean the bipoles have the same width as the lines, as @StefanH pointed out in his comment.
Setting also the line width, as pointed out by @GuilhermeZ.Santos, I can get the line width I would like to have.

Here the code snippet, and then the result.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, textcomp, gensymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw (0,0)
to [open, v^>=$V_{in}$, o-o] ++(0,3)
to ++(0.5,0)
to [L, l=$L_{RX}$, -] ++(1,0)
to [C, l=$C_{RX}$, -] ++(1,0)
to ++(0.5,0)
++(0,-3)
to [Do, l=$D_R$, *-*] ++(0, 3)
to ++(1,0)
++(0,-3)
to [C, l_=$C_D$, *-*] ++(0, 3)
to ++(0.5,0)
to [L, l=$L_C$, -] ++(1.5, 0)
to ++(0.5,0)
to [C, l=$C_{DC}$, *-*] ++(0, -3)
++(0,3)
to ++(1.5,0)
to [open, v^<=$V_{DC_{out}}$, o-o] ++(0,-3)
++(0,3)
to ++(2,0)
to [R, l=$R_L$, -] ++(0, -3)
to (0,0)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]