# CircuitTikZ: Change wire thickness for single wire(s)

Tags: circuitikz

while being used to using LaTeX for several years now, I am fairly new to using CircuitTikZ. I was wondering if it is possible to change the wire size of only one (/some) wire(s) in a circuit like in the following example:

[image: Sample image for clarification]

My MWE for drawing the circuit would be

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}[european]
        \draw (0,0) to[sinusoidal voltage source,label=$U$] (0,3) to[short, -*] (2,3) 
          to[lamp, l=$G$] (2,0) to[short, *-] (0,0);
        \draw (2,3) -- (4,3) to[short, l=$R$] (4,0)-- (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

And, I hope this is allowed to do here, I have a second question regarding the symbol of the voltage source: Does anyone know if there is a voltage source symbol consisting of the to empty circles like in the image above?

Kind regards and thank you for your help

Adrian

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338608/change-default-line-width-in-circuitikz

Comment: I had seen this post, but as far as I could see, this post described how to change line width globally, which was not, what I intended. Unfortunately, I was unable to extract how to individually change the wire thickness out of this post.

Comment: @AdrianLehrmann https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}[european]
        \draw (0,0) to[sinusoidal voltage source,label=$U$] (0,3) to[short, -*] (2,3) 
          to[lamp, l=$G$] (2,0) to[short, *-] (0,0);
        \draw [line width=3pt](2,3) -- (4,3) to[short, l=$R$] (4,0)-- (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @AdrianLehmann like to accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

Line thickness is a property of a path, so you need two different paths to have a different line thickness.

You have to consider too that several elements in `circuitikz` are affected by line thickness (for example, the sample `lamp` thing has line thickness that depends on the underlying line thickness).

You can do a game of mix and match by using `line width` and the component class styling (see the manual on page 32 and following). I like to keep that changes into `scope` environments.

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}[european]
        % thin line thing
        \draw (2,0) -| (0,1) to[open, o-o, l=$U$] (0,2) |- (2,3);
        % standard line width is 0.4pt. We go to double it
        \begin{scope}[line width=0.8pt]
            % lamp is a misc element: we can have it standard thickness with this
            \ctikzset{misc/thickness=1}% default is 2
            \draw (2,0) to[lamp, *-*] (2,3) -- (4,3) to [short, l=$R$] (4,0) -- (2,0);
        \end{scope}
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I faked your "generator" with a `short, o-o` element. There is an double-circle generator in the package, but it's quite different:

[image]