# How to specify line width in circuitikz style file ctikzstyle?

Tags: circuitikz

I have written a custom circuitikz style file but it doesn't apply the option `line width` specified in the tikz-level settings block in line 7.

My style file `ctikzstyle-mystyle.tex` with the name `mystyle`:

```
% Do not use LaTeX commands if you want it to be compatible with ConTeXt!
% Do not add spurious spaces!
%
\tikzset{mystyle circuit style/.style={%
% generic tikz-level settings
american,%
line width=1pt,% PROBLEM HERE
%
\circuitikzbasekey/.cd,%
% circutikz-level settings
%
% RESISTORS
resistors/scale=0.7,
resistors/thickness=1.0,
%
% CAPACITORS
capacitors/scale=0.7,
capacitors/thickness=1.0,
bipoles/capacitor/width/.initial=.13,
%
% GROUND
grounds/scale=1.0,
grounds/thickness=1.0,
%
% SOURCES (the round ones)
sources/scale=0.7,
sources/thickness=1.0,
%
% OTHER OPTIONS
bipoles/thickness=1,
nodes width/.initial=.03,
%
},% end .style
}% end \tikzset
\endinput
```

Here an example circuit:

```
\documentclass[border = 1cm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzsetstyle{mystyle}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) to[short, o-]  ++(1,  0)
                to[R]          ++(0, -2)
                to[short]      ++(1,  0) coordinate(e)
                to[short, *-o] ++(0, -1);

    \draw(4,0) to[short, o-] ++(-1,  0)
               to[isource]   ++( 0, -2)
               to[short] (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Both files, the example and the style file are in the same folder.

In principle the style file works but the `line width` doesn't change as expected. It has still the default value of `0.4pt` instead of `1pt`.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338608/change-default-line-width-in-circuitikz help?

Comment: I think the problem is that line width is reset at the start of any picture. Maybe this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389169/38080 helps?

Comment: @JohnKormylo that will set the line width of the components, not the standard used by, for example, `--` in diagrams.

Comment: @Rmano i just want to omit the optional argument of the circuitikz environment `\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]` out of laziness and i don't want to modify the line width in other tikzpictures. The solution in your link doesn't seem to save me from typing.

Comment: Unfortunately line width is globally set --- so the other option you have is to say `\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle circuit style] ...` with your original style --- it should work.

Comment: @Rmano i will use your last suggestion.  That way, one file contains the style definition and that is what I want.Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum change (from [Change all line width proportionally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389166/change-all-line-width-proportionally/389169#389169)) would be to change your "PROBLEM HERE" line with:

```latex
every picture/.append style={line width=1pt},
```

[image]

but notice that this will apply to all `tikzpicture` in the document. In the answer to the aforementioned linked question the is a more nuanced version.

If you do not want to apply the new line width to all `tikzpicture`s (and remember that `circuitikz` is just an alias for this), you can use your original style file but apply it explicitly to the circuits --- you can also give it a shortname:

```latex
\documentclass[border = 1cm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzloadstyle{mystyle} % maybe just load it, without setting as default
% shortcut
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={mystyle circuit style}}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle]
    \draw (0,0) to[short, o-]  ++(1,  0)
                to[R]          ++(0, -2)
                to[short]      ++(1,  0) coordinate(e)
                to[short, *-o] ++(0, -1);

    \draw(4,0) to[short, o-] ++(-1,  0)
               to[isource]   ++( 0, -2)
               to[short] (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

...and the result is the same.